# How to set up local Wordpress development environment using Nix without modifying flakes-based system configuration?

Tags: nix, nixos, nix-flake

I have NixOS 22.11 set up as on a local workstation. I'm looking for a way to create a customizable and flexible local environment for Wordpress development using Nix. I want the solution to be "ephemeral" (just drop-in config to any directory & run) and not modify my main system configuration (it uses flakes). I'm aware of tool like: [arion](https://docs.hercules-ci.com/arion/), but it uses `docker-compose` under the hood.

I need a solution that is equivalent to `docker-compose` in terms of easy setup of multiple, local Wordpress sites. However, it **must** use native NixOS configuration and Nix language to setup the needed services. It should be independent on `docker` or `podman`, but it should work with local `treafik` subdomains.

Currently, I'm using `traefik` routing with local subdomains. It is configured with `dnsmasq` and locally-trusted certificates using `mkcert`, as described in this [article](https://medium.com/soulweb-academy/docker-local-dev-stack-with-traefik-https-dnsmasq-locally-trusted-certificate-for-ubuntu-20-04-5f036c9af83d)

Here is my `docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  mariadb:

    image: bitnami/mariadb:latest
    volumes:
      - 'mariadb_data:/bitnami/mariadb'
    restart: always
    environment:

      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=wordpress
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=wordpress
      - MARIADB_USER=wordpress
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=wordpress
    networks:
      - web
    healthcheck:
      test: [ 'CMD', '/opt/bitnami/scripts/mariadb/healthcheck.sh' ]
      interval: 15s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 6

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:latest
    # command: -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    expose:
      - 8080
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - web

    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=mariadb
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress

    labels:
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.docker.network=web
      - traefik.http.routers.wp-http.entrypoints=web
      - traefik.http.routers.wp-http.rule=Host(`wp.docker.localdev`)
      - traefik.http.routers.wp-http.middlewares=wp-https
      - traefik.http.middlewares.wp-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https
      - traefik.http.routers.wp-https.entrypoints=websecure
      - traefik.http.routers.wp-https.rule=Host(`wp.docker.localdev`)
      - traefik.http.routers.wp-https.tls=true
      # - traefik.http.services.wp.loadbalancer.server.port=8080
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content

volumes:
  db_data:
  mariadb_data:
    driver: local

networks:
  web:
    external: true
```

Is it possible and how can I achieve this? I'm looking for more for a guidance: something like a code skeleton or even general tips are welcome.

Comment: This is a very open ended question. You've also mentioned other dependencies (wordpress, traefik) that I don't think are directly relevant to your question. I suggest you look into declarative containers in Nixos though.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i will check it. Yes i know, my question open, I also expect open answers and tips rather than complete solutions. I recently changed my system to NixOS and its a huge paradigm shift for me. The docker-compose based config works great for me on NixOS, but i wanted to learn how to do it Nix way.

Comment: I think, i found a potential solution for my needs: https://github.com/erikarvstedt/extra-container. I will fiddle around with the configs and post the answer in case of success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that meets my needs. The below config works for me, but it requires some fine-tuning.

I used [extra-container](https://github.com/erikarvstedt/extra-container), which can run **declarative NixOS containers** like imperative containers, without system rebuilds, from any folder.

The services used:

- nginx
- phpfpm
- mysql
- wordpress
- traefik for local subdomains. ( the subdomain name `.docker.localdev` might be misleading, I don't use docker here. I just had this name pre-configured in my system.

`wp.nix`

```
{ pkgs, lib, config, ... }:
let
  app = "wpdemo";
  socket = "/run/phpfpm/${app}.sock";
  domain = "localhost";
in
{
  containers.wp = {

    config = {
      networking.firewall.enable = false;
      security.acme.defaults.email = "admin@docker.localdev";
      networking.firewall.allowedTCPPorts = [ 80 82 ];
      services.traefik = {
        enable = true;
        staticConfigOptions = {
          providers.docker = {
            exposedByDefault = false;
          };
          entryPoints.web.address = ":80";
        };
        dynamicConfigOptions = {
          http.routers.wp = {
            rule = "Host(`wp.docker.localdev`)";
            entryPoints = [ "web" ];
            service = "wp-service";
          };
          http.services.wp-service.loadBalancer.server.port = 80;
        };
      };

      services.phpfpm.pools.${app} = {
        user = app;
        settings = {
          "listen.owner" = "nginx";
          "pm" = "dynamic";
          "pm.max_children" = 32;
          "pm.max_requests" = 500;
          "pm.start_servers" = 2;
          "pm.min_spare_servers" = 2;
          "pm.max_spare_servers" = 5;
          "php_admin_value[error_log]" = "stderr";
          "php_admin_flag[log_errors]" = true;
          "catch_workers_output" = true;
        };
        phpEnv."PATH" = lib.makeBinPath [ pkgs.php ];
      };

      services.mysql = {
        enable = true;
        package = pkgs.mariadb;
        settings = {
          "mysqld" = {
            "port" = 3308;
          };
        };
        initialScript =
          pkgs.writeText "initial-script" ''
            CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS wordpress;
            CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
            GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
          '';

        ensureDatabases = [
          "wordpress"
        ];
        ensureUsers = [
          {
            name = "admin";
            ensurePermissions = {
              "admin.*" = "ALL PRIVILEGES";
              "*.*" = "ALL PRIVILEGES";
            };
          }
        ];
      };

      systemd.services.wordpress.serviceConfig = {
        ProtectSystem = lib.mkForce false;
        ProtectHome = lib.mkForce false;
        ReadWritePaths = [ "/var" "/home" "/home/www" ];
      };


      systemd.services.wpsetup = {
        path = with pkgs; [ coreutils wget gzip curl unzip rsync ];
        wantedBy = [ "multi-user.target" ];
        script = ''
         
          mkdir -p /var/www/wpdemo

          # WordPress
          cd  /var/www/wpdemo
          curl -L https://wordpress.org/latest.zip -o wordpress.zip 
          unzip wordpress.zip -d ./tmp
          mv ./tmp/*/* .
          rm -rf tmp
          rm ./wordpress.zip

          #  Storefront theme
          cd  /var/www/wpdemo/wp-content/themes
          curl -L https://downloads.wordpress.org/theme/storefront.4.2.0.zip -o storefront.zip
          unzip storefront.zip
          rm storefront.zip

          #  WooCommerce plugin
          cd  /var/www/wpdemo/wp-content/plugins
          curl -L https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/woocommerce.7.4.1.zip -o woocommerce.zip
          unzip woocommerce.zip
          rm woocommerce.zip
          chmod 777 -R  /var/www/wpdemo
        '';
        serviceConfig = {
          ProtectSystem = lib.mkForce false;
          ProtectHome = lib.mkForce false;
          ReadWritePaths = [ "/var" "/home" "/home/wpdemo" "/home/wpdemo/www" ];
        };
      };

      systemd.services.ngnix.serviceConfig = {

        ProtectSystem = lib.mkForce false;
        ProtectHome = lib.mkForce false;
        ReadWritePaths = [ "/var" "/home" "/home/wpdemo" "/home/wpdemo/www" ];
      };
      services.nginx = {
        enable = true;

        virtualHosts.${domain} = {
          listen = [{
            addr = "127.0.0.1";
            port = 80;
          }];
          serverName = "wp.docker.localdev";

          locations."/" = {
            root = "/var/www/wpdemo";
            extraConfig = ''
              access_log off;
              charset utf-8;
              etag off;
              index index.php;
              
              location ~ \.php$ {
                  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                  fastcgi_pass  unix:${socket};
                  include ${pkgs.nginx}/conf/fastcgi_params;
                  include ${pkgs.nginx}/conf/fastcgi.conf;
              }
            '';
          };
        };
      };

      users.mutableUsers = true;

      users.users.${app} = {
        isSystemUser = true;
        createHome = true;
        home = "/home/wpdemo";
        group = app;
      };
      users.groups.${app} = { };
    };
    # bindMounts = {
    #   "/var/www/wpdemo/wp-content/themes" = {
    #     hostPath = "/var/www/wpdemo/wp-content/themes/";
    #     isReadOnly = false;
    #   };
    # };
  };

}
```

I run it with the command:

```
sudo extra-container create --start <<EOF
$(cat wp.nix)
EOF
```

Comment: possible to use that with direnv?

Comment: I don't know. Personally i don't use direnv.